# Preloading SVGs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, svg, preloading

I am aware that javascript can make use of the Image() object to prime images before output, however I need the same functionality for SVGs. I don't want to be loading it into an "img" tag but rather building the SVG markup in javascript and ensuring the src files are loaded before I dump them to the screen. Does any one know if this is possible and how to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just retrieve your SVG files via a usual AJAX-GET request and insert the code upon success of this request.

```
$.get( 'path/to/your/svg/file.svg', function(data) {
  $('#svgContainer').html( data );
});
```

Comment: This is an idea, however the SVG is being dynamically created at runtime (see Raminson's answer). I was hoping to use the SVGs onload event, but it only seems to work on static SVGs. I tried adding the onload event dynamically to my js SVG object, but it never fires. The odd thing is that click events DO fire using this method. **Any idea how to get the SVG load event to fire from a dynamically generated SVG?**

Comment: `svg.addEventListener('SVGLoad', function() {
    alert("loaded!") 
});` // DOES NOT ALERT.... :(

Answer (score 1):

you can use `createElementNS()`:

```
var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'height','536');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'width','536');
img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/SVG_Simple_Logo.svg');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'x','10');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'y','10');
img.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');
$('svg').append(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an <iframe>, add an event listener for 'load' on the iframe and then set the src of the iframe to the svg you want to load.

E.g:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
  ... svg now loaded, do something ...
});
iframe.src = "your.svg";
```

If you want you can import the elements into the main document, just note that you need to either [import](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Core-Document-importNode) or [adopt](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Document3-adoptNode) the nodes into the main document before trying to append them.

It's probably more natural to just use XmlHttpRequest like Sirko suggested.